# Conversion a datetime object extracted from a .ics file to local datetime

Tags: php

I have a ics file and i extracted these information in order to write some code to add a meeting on a custom calendar based on Google Calendar :

DTSTART:20210802T080000Z

DTEND:20210802T090000Z

I'am using Sabre\VObject to reach my goal.

I am in Paris and the meeting start normaly at 10 o'clock, but by using
`$vcalendar->VEVENT->DTSTART->getDateTime();`

I'am getting a DateTime object with 2021:08:02 08:00, and i need to convert this to 10:00:00 which is Paris local time.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a source and destination timezone and use that in the code to work out a DateInterval and use that to report the time in Paris time, like this

```
$inDT = '20210802T080000';

$sourceTimezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris');

$myDateTime = new DateTime($inDT, $sourceTimezone);
$offset = $userTimezone->getOffset($myDateTime);

$myInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString((string)$offset . 'seconds');
$myDateTime->add($myInterval);

$result = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $result;
```

RESULT

```
2021-08-02 10:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much RiggsFolly. I found somewhere on the web something like what you just wrote but it failed, it says that the value of offset was 0. But your code works perfectly. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that i can reach my goal by simply using `setTimeZone()`.

In fact, when you have a DateTime Object, you can simply use

`$dateobject->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')`

And you can get your local time datetime object, and it is more simple than RiggsFolly solution, in my case of course.